# How to execute generic query in ArangoJs?

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

I need to execute the following query:

```
const query = `FOR u IN ${collection} FILTER ${filter} RETURN u`
```

so that `filter` variable is generated somehow by me (it is corrects, checked with Arango console)

But

```
db.query(query)
```

always returns empty cursor, and

```
db.query(aql`FOR u IN ${db.collection(collection)} FILTER ${filter} RETURN u`)
```

ignores my filter - data is not filtered.

How to execute query with arangojs with pre-generated filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix: db.query(query).all() worked